# How to edit *.mmgl model files?

Tags: modeling

I have 4 models in *.mmgl format. Is there any way I can edit them using Blender? If not, what software do I need to use?

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea. What program did they come from? where did you get them? what kind of data do they hold?

Comment: I believe *.mmgl stands for CMemoryModelGL.